# Can we make snapshot to the physical machine?

Tags: linux, snapshot, vmware-workstation

All we know we can snapshot(store the current system and disk information) the VM in the VMware workstation easily.

[image]

But I don't know if we can snapshot to the  physical machine (CentOS 7.2).

Or use some tools to do that?

Comment: Can you tell us what is a "snapshot to the physical machine"? AFAIK, VmWare snapshots are written on your disk.

Comment: @xhienne I mean store the current system and disk information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot safely store a whole machine state within the machine.

But similar actions are possible if you accept certain limitations. You can use a file system (e.g. btrfs, xfs) which supports snapshots for both your OS and data volume(s). Alternatively you can use LVM snapshots with any file system.

In addition you would have to backup the partition table and boot loader sectors. In addition maybe even the EFI data but I am not familiar with it how that can be restored.